# XPath - Selecting nodes with one similar and one different attribute

Tags: xslt, xpath

So I'm having trouble understanding why one XPath expression gets the nodes I want, while the other doesn't.

First, the xml:

```
<doc>
    <source id="225" clientID="567" matterID="225" level="2" />
    <source id="226" clientID="993" matterID="226" level="2" />
    <dest id="185" level="7" />
    <dest id="226" level="7" />
</doc>
```

The keys in my xsl template are defined as follows:

```
<xsl:key name="sourceId" match="//source" use="@id" />
<xsl:key name="destId" match="//dest" use="@id" />
<xsl:key name="destLevel" match="//dest" use="@level" />
```

What I'm looking for are the source nodes, that match dest nodes on id, but have a different level attribute. The apply template that I figured would work in my head is the following:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="source[key('destId', @id) and not(key('destLevel', @level))]" mode="update" />
```

But that doesn't seem to work. A colleague suggested putting a not around an expression that matches the nodes I don't want, and after a lot of trial and error, I thought this might work, to no effect:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="source[not(not(key('destId', @id)) or not(key('destLevel', @level)))]" mode="update" />
```

Can anyone please walk me through what I need in order to solve this?

**Edit:** I previously thought I'd solved this with the second query, but it seems I was mistaken.

**====Solution====**

Dimitre Novatchev has a detailed breakdown of different ways to solve this, but my ultimate solution was actually slightly different than his.

In essence, I created a virtual key with the concat() function that combined the two attributes. That way, I could find nodes that matched the id, but not the id-level combo.

Extra key:

```
<xsl:key name="destByIdAndLevel" match="//dest" use="concat(@id,'+',@level)" />
```

Changed apply-template call:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="source[key('destId', @id) and not(key('destByIdAndLevel',concat(@id,'+',@level)))]" mode="update" />
```

Comment: Can you post a complete but minimal stylesheet with xml doc showing the problem? Your first query works for me on the given xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I. This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="source">
   <xsl:copy-of select=
     "self::*[../dest[@id = current()/@id and not(@level=current()/@level)]]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (an additional `source` element added to the provided XML document -- to verify more cases):

```
<doc>
 <source id="185" clientID="567" matterID="225" level="7" />
 <source id="225" clientID="567" matterID="225" level="2" />
 <source id="226" clientID="993" matterID="226" level="2" />
 <dest id="185" level="7" />
 <dest id="226" level="7" />
</doc>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<source id="226" clientID="993" matterID="226" level="2"/>
```

---

**II. Solution using one key**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kDestById" match="dest" use="@id"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "source[key('kDestById',@id)
         and
           not(@level=key('kDestById',@id)/@level)]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), again the same wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<source id="226" clientID="993" matterID="226" level="2"/>
```

---

**III. Solution with two keys**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kDestById" match="dest" use="@id"/>
 <xsl:key name="kDestByLevel" match="dest" use="@level"/>

 <xsl:template match="source">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "self::*
        [key('kDestById',@id)
       and
         key('kDestById',@id)
             [not(count(.|key('kDestByLevel',current()/@level))
                 =
                  count(key('kDestByLevel',current()/@level))
                 )
             ]
        ]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**This again produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
 <source id="226" clientID="993" matterID="226" level="2"/>
```

Comment: Brilliant stuff. Absolutely excellent. I actually ended up going with a hybrid of solution II and III, where I built a second key with a use="concat(@id,'+',@level)", then is was just a matter of narrowing down the select to source(key('destId',@id and not(key('destByIdAndLevel',concat(@id,'+',@level))).

Answer (score 1):

```
source[key('destId', @id) and not(key('destLevel', @level))]
```

This gives source nodes which have an id the same as some dest nodes, and also have a level which is not the same as any dest nodes. Note that it doesn't require a **particular** dest node to have the same id but different level.

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
source[set:difference(key('destId', @id), key('destLevel', @level))]
```

[set:difference()](http://www.exslt.org/set/functions/difference/index.html) is from EXSLT.